# What should be done to make my own weighted loss function for BertForSequenceClassification?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model

I am trying to fine tune SciBERT with a new dataset, but my dataset is having a high imbalance among classes (the class with highest number of elements has ~760 elements, while there are classes with 10-20 elements). Due to this problem, I am trying to make my own weighted loss function (using logits) for the fine-tuning process; however from what I read, I would have to write my own loss function with PyTorch though, and I am not sure how to integrate that class with my code.

Here is my current code though, for reference:

```
import transformers
import torch

cuda = torch.device('cuda')

tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizer.from_pretrained("allenai/scibert_scivocab_uncased", 
    max_length=512)
bert = transformers.BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('scibert_single_label_model').to(cuda).train()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2, shuffle=True)

def _tokenize(instances: list[str]):
    return tokenizer(instances, return_tensors='pt', padding='max_length', truncation=True, max_length=512).input_ids

def _encode_labels(labels):
    """:labels: should be the `labels` column (a Series) of the DataFrame"""
    return torch.Tensor(encoder.transform(labels))

x_train = _tokenize(train['text'].tolist())

y_train = _encode_labels(train[['label']])


NUM_EPOCHS = 6

from statistics import mean

from tqdm import tqdm
from torch.optim import AdamW

optim = AdamW(bert.parameters(), lr=2e-5, eps=1e-8)

for epoch in range(NUM_EPOCHS):
    epoch_losses = []
    for x, y in tqdm(_load_data(x_train, y_train, batch_size=10)):
        bert.zero_grad()
        out = bert(x, attention_mask=x.ne(tokenizer.pad_token_id).to(int), labels=y)
        epoch_losses.append(out.loss.item())
        out.loss.backward()
        optim.step()
```

So, could you provide me with ideas about how I could add my own customized weighted loss function to this code?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are working with PyTorch you can create your own loss function `nn module`, an example is given as follows:

```html
class LabelSmoothedCrossEntropyLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, label_smoothing=0.0, num_classes=10):
        super(LabelSmoothedCrossEntropyLoss, self).__init__()
        self.smoothing = label_smoothing

    def forward(self, x, target):
        confidence  = 1. - self.smoothing
        logprobs    = F.log_softmax(x, dim=-1)
        nll_loss    = -logprobs.gather(dim=-1, index=target.unsqueeze(1))
        nll_loss    = nll_loss.squeeze(1)
        smooth_loss = -logprobs.mean(dim=-1)
        loss = confidence * nll_loss + self.smoothing * smooth_loss
        return loss.mean()

# Call the loss function
criterion = LabelSmoothedCrossEntropyLoss(label_smoothing=0.1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your ideas @tonyjo, and I already looked through these suggestions earlier (from Huggingface and from GitHub). My point here is, after writing my own loss function (or modify the BertForSequenceClassification class), what should I do to integrate the new loss function to my current code (so ```out = bert(x, attention_mask=x.ne(tokenizer.pad_token_id).to(int), labels=y)``` in this case)?